# Latex3 Getting values of multiple keys from a property list

Tags: expl3, latex3, l3prop

The following code works correctly.

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_const_from_keyval:Nn \argsDic{r=\vec{r}, e=E, t=t}
\NewDocumentCommand{\args}{m}
{
\prop_get:NnN \argsDic {#1} \tl_var
(\tl_var)
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

But the problem is that the function `\prop_get` only returns the value associated with one key. I want to know if there is a function that accepts a list of keys and returns the list of their associated values. Something like this

```
...
\prop_get_multiple:NnN ⟨property list⟩ {⟨key1⟩,⟨key2⟩,...,⟨keyN⟩} {⟨value1⟩,⟨value2⟩,...,⟨valueN⟩}
...
```

Comment: no, but you can use a loop over a clist of keys.